# How to add a GCE user to a group that persists membership?

Tags: linux, bash, cloud, google-compute-engine, redhat

In my RHEL7 instance on GCE I use a software package I installed from the commandline using its bash scripted installer. The installer creates a user xyz the software runs under, and a group xyzgroup, and adds both user xyz and the user who ran the installer (eg. gce_user) to the xyzgroup group. But the GCE google-accounts-daemon.service (GAD) periodically removes user gce_user from the group xyzgroup :

```
sudo systemctl -l status google-accounts-daemon.service
[...]
Aug 03 23:36:18 rhel7-n4 usermod[7702]: delete 'gce_user' from group 'xyzgroup'
Aug 03 23:36:18 rhel7-n4 usermod[7702]: delete 'gce_user' from shadow group 'xyzgroup'
Aug 23 05:12:36 rhel7-n4 usermod[26008]: delete 'gce_user' from group 'xyzgroup'
Aug 23 05:12:36 rhel7-n4 usermod[26008]: delete 'gce_user' from shadow group 'xyzgroup'
Sep 05 20:59:26 rhel7-n4 usermod[21884]: delete 'gce_user' from group 'xyzgroup'
Sep 05 20:59:26 rhel7-n4 usermod[21884]: delete 'gce_user' from shadow group 'xyzgroup'
```

However the GAD does not remove the user xyz from the group xyzgroup . I created the user gce_user using the GCE cloud console when creating the instance and added the ssh keys to that user; the installer added user gce_user to group xyzgroup but it didn't persist. I used `sudo gpasswd -a gce_user xyzgroup` to restore the user to the group but that didn't persist. I also used `sudo usermod -a -G xyzgroup gce_user` to restore user gce_user to group xyzgroup but that didn't persist either. GAD deleted the user from the group sometimes several days after the user was added to the group.

I note that the [GCE Accounts daemon account_utils.py calls usermod](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-packages/blob/master/google_compute_engine/accounts/accounts_utils.py#L145) to add a user to groups:

```
command = ['usermod', '-G', groups, user]
```

The GCE docs say that the cloud console can be used to manage (Linux OS) user accounts, including (Linux OS) group membership: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/#create_a_new_user_account

However, the instructions start with: 1. Go to the [User Accounts page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/useraccounts/).

That link to the User Accounts page will require you to select a project. Once selected, the resulting page is not the User Accounts page - it's the project's overall Dashboard page. If you enter into the search bar at the top of the Dashboard page [user accounts] and click the item User accounts (subtitled IAM & Admin), the resulting page just says "(!) Failed to load".

How do I add user gce_user to group xyzusers so that group membership persists, and isn't deleted by GAD? Preferably a commandline so I can fix the xyz software package's installer bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud User Accounts feature is in beta which requires whitelisting.

> This is a Beta release of User Accounts. This feature might be changed in backward-incompatible ways and is not recommended for production use. It is not subject to any SLA or deprecation policy. Request to be whitelisted to use this feature.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/user-accounts/#useraccountsgroups

Comment: Seems like a lot of red tape to enable baseline functionality of a core Linux administration feature, but I requested it, thanks for highlighting that.

Comment: I guess it's for security. They want to make it part of the vm meta data.

Comment: Legitimate concern, but the groups metadata in the OS (ie. /etc/group etc) should just be monitored by a GCE container service, populating the VM metadata. Or revise the OS tools for maintaining that OS metadata (etc gpasswd , usermod ) to also manage the VM metadata. This architecture that forces sysadmins to also use a GCloud tool is bad workflow. And while forcing a whitelist request granted through email is hopefully just an artifact of the beta release, the whole infrastructure should disappear on real release.

Comment: The beta group added me after evaluating my use case as appropriate to their features. They're still developing the system and its APIs.